# Running forms and VBA code from C# on an Access 2003 database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Pretty much what it says on the tin. I've tried googling around but can't find anything helpful.

I'm trying to automate a process and part of that involves running forms/VBA code from an access 2003 database. What's the best way to call these from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B897646) let you to automate Access 2003 from your C# application. In particular, you should be able to use commands like `DoCmd.OpenForm` and `DoCmd.RunCode`, allowing you to run your Access 2003 forms and VBA code.

Comment: I've linked to the Microsoft Office 12 Object Library and I have the Microsoft.Office.Core namespace, but I can't find any mention of DoCmd etc.

Comment: Add the Microsoft Access 11.0 Object Library and have a look at the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access namespace.

Comment: Here's an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159913(office.11).aspx
The example code is in VB.NET, but the concept is exactly the same for C#.

Comment: That's got me one step closer, but now it's complaining that it can't find the file system.mdw and that This file is required for startup.

Comment: It's looking for it in C:\WINNT\system32

Comment: Nevermind, I added the newest refernece ( 10 instead of 8) and it works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Create the VBA code in a separate COM dll, and then you can use COM interop to call from C#

For instance, see SO question: [Using a COM dll from C# without a type library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037786/using-a-com-dll-from-c-without-a-type-library).

> [**Exposing COM Components to C#**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx)
>
> You can consume a COM component from a
>   C# project. The general steps are as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Locate a COM component to use and register it. Use regsvr32.exe to
>      register or un–register a COM DLL.
> 2. Add to the project a reference to the COM component or type library.
>
> When you add the reference, Visual
>   Studio uses the Type Library Importer
>   (Tlbimp.exe), which takes a type
>   library as input, to output a .NET
>   Framework interop assembly. The
>   assembly, also named a runtime
>   callable wrapper (RCW), contains
>   managed classes and interfaces that
>   wrap the COM classes and interfaces
>   that are in the type library. Visual
>   Studio adds to the project a reference
>   to the generated assembly.
>
> 3. Create an instance of a class that is defined in the RCW. This, in turn,
>      creates an instance of the COM object.
> 4. Use the object just as you use other managed objects. When the object
>      is reclaimed by garbage collection,
>      the instance of the COM object is also
>      released from memory.

Comment: This doesn't help me with calling VBA code that's heavily entangled with the database, putting code that calls specific queries in a dll wouldn't work. My main need is more the automation, opening a "connection" to the database and telling it to run a certain piece of vba code